# Run Unity3D standalone game within a Docker container

Tags: docker, unity-game-engine

This might be trivial or might be not even possible, but I spent the last day trying to find a way to run the standalone executable built by Unity3D inside a Docker container.

The Unity3D editor runs on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine, and the `project.86_64` runs without issues there. However, I would like to have that same standalone game run within a dedicated Docker container.

Right now I tried using an ubuntu Docker image, importing into it the built files, connecting the container to the XServer (with the whole `xauth`, `export DISPLAY`, and such, which should work, as I have a python GUI displayed from another container) but when I start the executable it hangs without prompting any error. My assumption is that it's waiting for a display or something along those lines, but I've no clue about it (tried to look for the application log but found nothing of sort in the executable's folder).
Another - very plausible - possibility is that I'm missing some dependency in the container, but I wasn't able to find which ones were needed by the standalone game (if any).

In case it matters, Unity3D version is 2020.3 (Free Version), Ubuntu 20.04 machine, `ubuntu:latest` image.

Thanks in advance!

*Why tho?* The reason for this weird setup is, long story short, that I'm trying to deploy a 3-pieces app "python-Node.JS-Unity3D" as 3 containers using docker-compose, communicating in their own separate network. Convoluted and probably unnecessary, I know, bear with me.

Comment: Did you manage to make this work, @hypothe?

Comment: With many manual steps, I was able to make Unity work on the image `unityci/editor:ubuntu-2020.3.34f1-linux-il2cpp-1.0.1`, but it runs on `Ubuntu 18.04` and I really need to make it un on `Ubuntu 20.04`

Comment: @RubenAlves glad you found a way! I unfortunately had to change my plan a bit and I ended up running the simulation/game in its WebGL, using a NodeJS server docker to serve it. Had to change quite a few things because my simulation was using sockets to communicate with python code, but everything went pretty smooth in the end.

Comment: Hello Ruben, can you give some basic steps on how you got it to work?  I have been working with the unityci containters.

Comment: Hi @RubenAlves could you please help by going through the steps you took? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hi @Kelvin, it has been a long time ago. I don't remember how I did it because I'm on a different project now. Sorry for not being able to help now. May God help you find the answer your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Probably is because of the GPU, which is not recognized by the container. I solved it by using following docker compose file:

```
unity:
  image: unityci/editor:ubuntu-2021.3.3f1-base-1
  volumes:
    - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    - ${XAUTHORITY}:${XAUTHORITY}
    - $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
  environment:
    - XAUTHORITY
    - DISPLAY
    - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
    - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
    - NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all
  deploy:
    resources:
      reservations:
        devices:
          - capabilities: [gpu]
```